# In Cypress component tests, changes to window object made inside component render cycle do not persevere

Tags: reactjs, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner, window-object

I need to expose some of my component's internals to Cypress component tests via `window` object, but I'm failing to pass and read it properly. Consider this code:

```js
// component
import React, { FC } from 'react'

(window as any).publicDictionary = { }
export const getPublicDict = () => (window as any).publicDictionary
const addToPublicDict = (id: string) => (window as any).publicDictionary[id] = true

addToPublicDict('foo')

export const MyComponent: FC = () => {
   addToPublicDict('bar')
   return null
}
```

```js
// test
it('Applies default value', () => {
   mount(<MyComponent/>)

   const dict = getPublicDict();

   cy.log({
      window,
      dict,
      foo: dict.foo,
      bar: dict.bar,
      dictKeys: Object.keys(dict),
   } as any)
})
```

This code behaves very weirdly when inspected via Chrome devtools:
[image]

... when logging `publicDict` directly, both `foo` and `bar` properties seem to be present - but when I try to access them, `bar` turns out to be `undefined`, because it was set inside the component's render cycle. `foo`, on the other hand, can be read and accessed as expected.

What is going on? What can I do to successfully pass my component's internals to Cypress in component tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found the cause, but I found the solution.

`window` object only works properly for me, when I access it while chained after  [cy.window command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/window):

```
import { getPublicDict } from './utils'

// This works:
it('works', () => {
  cy.window().then(() => {
    // Here, window and its properties work as expected
    const dict = getPublicDict();  
  })
})

// This doesn't:
it('works', () => {
  // Here, window tends to get quite quirky
  const dict = getPublicDict(); 
})
```

This way it works well - I don't even have to use the `window` object yielded by `cy.window` - it's sufficient I access `window` while chained after `cy.window`.

If anyone knows why this is, I'm curious.

Answer (score 3):

You're exporting `export const getPublicDict...` so import it like this

```js
import {getPublicDict} from '../src/my-component'
```

With this import, the properties show up.

Note, the `window` object isn't the same in test and app. In component testing they mount the component on the test runner window.

Comment: You are wrong. I obviously do import the function - how else did you think I manage to call it with `dict` and `dict.foo` being accessible in the return value?

Comment: Yes it works, I just tried it. Obviously you are importing in the wrong way.